# How to pass a value using `createContext` from parent to child's child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, createcontext

Instead of passing `props` from parent to child1(parent of child2) ->to child2,
I want to use `createContext` and receive the value with `useContext`.

 What I tried to do is not correct because and I'm getting an error `**'booleanContext' is not defined`**.

How can I pass the `createContext` state/value ?

App.js

 CreatePass is a component inside SignUp

```js
  const [signUpFirst, setIfSignUp] = useState(true);
  const booleanContext = createContext(setIfSignUp);
  
 return (
    <booleanContext.Provider value={setIfSignUp}>

   <div>
     </Switch>
   <Route exact path='/signup'>
          <SignUp homePage={exitSignUpPage} setUserNumber={setUserID} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path='/home'>
          <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
      <CreatPass /> 
      </Switch>
     </div>
    </booleanContext.Provider>
  );
```

SignUp.js

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='signUp-div'>
        <Header />
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className='form-div'>
            <Redirect to='/signup/mobile' />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/signup/mobile' component={MobileNum} />
              <Route exact path='/signup/idnumber'>
                <IdentNumber setPersonalID={this.props.setUserNumber} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/signup/password'>
                <CreatePass />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

CreatePass.js  //**`'booleanContext' is not defined  no-undef`**

```js
const CreatePass = () => {
  const changeBooleanValue = useContext(booleanContext);

  const handleClickButton = () => {
      changeBooleanValue(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className='form-div'>
  <button onClick={handleClickButton}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CreatePass;
```

### Edit - Update:

This solution is **not good** it's the same value as I did above, `booleanContext` is undefined -

```js
export const booleanContext = createContext(); // default value is undefiend
...
const App = () => 
     return(
     <booleanContext.Provider value={setIfSignUp}>
      <CreatPass />        
     </booleanContext.Provider>
      )
}
export default App;
```

Will be glad for explanations

Answer (score 6):

for context provider and consumer, usually I create 1 hook for it like `useBoolean.tsx` that return `BooleanProvider` component that you can put inside your parent and `useBoolean` function that you can import inside your child component.

Basically any global function should wrap all its children inside its `Provider`.

So, if you want `<CreatePass/>` to access the value from the provider, it needs to be a children of its `Provider`

```
<BooleanProvider>
  <CreatePass/>
</BooleanProvider>
```

`useBoolean.tsx` will have something like this

```
// useBoolean.tsx
const BooleanContext = createContext()

export const BooleanProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [signUpFirst, setIfSignUp] = useState(true)

  return (
    <BooleanContext.Provider value={{ signUpFirst, setIfSignUp }}>
      {children}
    </BooleanContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useBoolean = () => {
  const context = useContext(BooleanContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`${useBoolean.name} must be within ${BooleanProvider.name}`)
  }
  return context
}
```

Parent component will be like usual

```
// Parent component
import { BooleanProvider } from 'hooks/useBoolean'

const Parent = () => (
  <BooleanProvider>
    <Child1 />
  </BooleanProvider>
)
```

Child1 will have Child2 and Child2 will use the useBoolean function we created

```
// Child1 component
const Child1 = () => (
  <div>
    <Child2 />
  </div>
)

// Child2 component
import { useBoolean } from 'hooks/useBoolean'

const Child2 = () => {
  const { setIfSignUp } = useBoolean()

  return <div></div>
}
```

Hope this helps clarify something for you. I am just trying to explain my understanding here on using the react context api and my way of doing it as well.

I tried to create hooks function like this for easier code management - it helps me understand what this context does directly with hooks naming convention. The hook function throws error too when it is not being used inside the `Provider` :D. Cheers !

Comment: I think `const BooleanContext = createContext({})` should be initialised as null instead of object.

Comment: Yea right. thanks for that man.. if it is undefined / null.. then the throw error will work in the hooks..

Answer (score 1):

Move "const booleanContext = createContext(setIfSignUp);" Outside of the component, you dont want to change context reference every render. Also export it for other components.

```
export const booleanContext = createContext(); // default value is undefiend
...
const App = () => ...

export default App;
```

Then in CreatePass, you should import context (used named export, so import would be like this:

```
import { booleanContext } from '..somePath../App'
```

Now it should work.

## EDIT:

Works as expected
https://codesandbox.io/s/createcontexttest-0qvvm?file=/src/App.js

## EDIT 2

```
<App>
  <CreatePass /> // there is value undefined
  <Context.Provider value={'something'}>
    <CreatePass /> // value is defined
    <SignUp>
       <CreatePass /> // also defined
    </SignUp>
  </Context.Provider>
  <div>
    <CreatePass /> // undefined
  </div>
</App>
```

Comment: I already tried that, in `CreatePass ` it is `undefined`. booleanContext / the name I gave it - `changeBooleanValue` is `undefined`. not a good solution.

Comment: I tried it in sandbox (link in edit) and it works as expected, maybe try "debugger;", if all values are passed ok.

Comment: Your CodeSandbox link is an empty project, please check.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/createcontexttest-0qvvm?file=/src/App.js

Tried to rename it, try now

Comment: That because `CreatePass` is not inside `SignUp` component. I changed it in your codesandbox and got this error - `changeBooleanValue is not a function`. App.js - ```return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox, value: {"" + signUpFirst}</h1>
      <Switch>
        <Route>
          <SignUp />
        </Route>
        </Switch>
      <booleanContext.Provider value={setIfSignUp}>
        <CreatePass />
      </booleanContext.Provider>
     
    </div>
  );``` And fixed `SignUp` component to be the parent of `Createpass`

Comment: In this way of yours I can just pass props to `CreatePass`  but wanted better way with - `createContext`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This answer is correct. Your original error was simply because, as it said, `changeBooleanValue` was not defined in that file. You need to export it from somewhere and import in `CreatePass`. This has nothing at all to do with React.

Comment: Also components, that want to useContext value should be inside provider (as a child) - EDIT 2

Comment: It can be sometimes confusing, in that case i would recommend trying redux - you wouldnt need contexts, instead, dispatch actions from anywhere and redux updates only components, that changed.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks ok. You can fix the default value error when exporting the context with an empty object `{}`.

```
export const booleanContext = createContext({}); 
export default function App() {
    ...
    return (
     <booleanContext.Provider value={setIfSignUp}>
         ...
     </booleanContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and import it `CreatePass.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { booleanContext } from "./App";

const CreatePass = () => {
     const changeBooleanValue = useContext(booleanContext);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first, create a custom component for your context provider:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const CustomContext = createContext(["green", () => {}]);

export default CustomContext;
```

then wrap all your components using it in for example App.js:

```
<CustomContext.Provider value={options}>
  […]
</CustomContext.Provider>
```

and then you can use it as follows:

```
import CustomContext from "./CustomContext";

// top of SearchParams function body
const [options] = useContext(CustomContext);
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting  component `createPass` over other components in a one page, and if I ignore it (and passing all the process in the sign-up) I'm getting an error - `TypeError: changeBooleanValue is not a function`.

Comment: I don't need a custom component in my App.js. because the -  `const [signUpFirst, setIfSignUp] = useState(true);` is used inside the App.js

Comment: if you mean `const changeBooleanValue = useContext(booleanContext);` section, absolutely its wrong! u should use `const [_, changeBooleanValue] = useContext(booleanContext);` instead.

Comment: I don't get it - `changeBooleanValue ` is the name that choose to give it at `CreatePass` component. Your code example is not as mine.

Comment: yous said that you encounter with `TypeError: changeBooleanValue is not a function` error. it is due to the fact that`useState` returns the current state and also the second parameter is setFunction for that variable.

Comment: I'm passing only the setState - `setIfSignUp` with the Provider, did you see that?